# In playwright my methods in a tests are not running in the order I mentioned them? why?

Tags: automation, playwright, playwright-typescript

test('Check the components of CRM - Inquiry page by entering valid details ', async ({  }) => {

```
const { helpCenter, contactUs, cRM, cRMSuccess } = pages;

await helpCenter.homeCenter_ContactUs.click();
await contactUs.clickRegisterYourInterest();  
await cRM.checkVisibility();   
await cRM.enterNameAndEmail();
await cRM.enterPhoneNumber();
await cRM.enterStudyDestination();
await cRM.enterCourseType();
await cRM.enterEducationField();
await cRM.enterStudyYear();
await cRM.enterContactTime();
await cRM.clickSubmitButton();
await cRMSuccess.handlePopup();
await cRMSuccess.cRMSuccessPopup();
```

});

The methods i mentioned here in the above test are not executing in order mentioned above due to which my test is failing

Comment: The required information is missing. There is neither definitions of functions in question nor the overall config details. Please think carefully and add all the required information you will need yourself if somebody asked you this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example